# Is there an event on electron based app's uninstall, for Mac? Or a way to distinguish between an install and an update?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I see that there's options for windows with NSIS but nothing for mac.

I want to give users an option to cleanup app related files when they uninstall the app. But I haven't found an event on which I can trigger this on mac side.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no such events as you want for mac os. It's only provided for windows. uninstalling an app on macOS is you need to just drag it over to the trash. so, if you want to remove app-related files to be deleted then just remove `app.getPath("home")` data before `autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()`.

Comment: I actually don't want it to be removed on each update. The only solution I have found for this is https://stackoverflow.com/a/57782074/1724300 but in my opinion it's a patch rather than a solution.

Comment: what do you want then? if you don't want it to be removed in each update?